# Does anyone know what’s wrong with my Areca Palm?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, diseases, plant-care

I’m quite new to this, honestly should have done this earlier. I got plants to keep me company in this lonely place as I’m in uni, I’ve had my plants since September and to be honest it’s been a long winter I’m glad they were doing well until maybe early December late November. The roots stopped absorbing water. I didn’t water them too frequently, I thought it might have been because there wasn’t enough sun or that it was cold. (I’m currently making plans to find an alternate source of light.) I had realised that they weren’t taking in water until it was too late.

The leaves started dying, turning brown at the tips. Then there was almost like a fungus growing on the base of the soil. So I looked it up and it said it’s cause I overwatered and I hadn’t to act quickly or else they’d die. So I went out, bought new bags of fresh soil. Repotted then and started monitoring them. 80% of the leaves are still green. They’re absorbing water now but still they seem to be dying. I went out and bought anti fungus stuff and things that promote growth. And they started to look a bit better. I pulled out the dead leaves and kept the healthy ones and there were signs of new life!! But still, the white dots persisted. Now they’re dying again and I honestly don’t know what to do anymore I’m so stressed.

Currently:

1.The leaves have brown spots on them, almost black.
2. The bottom of the stems have this white dot/ almost powdery substance on them.
3. I opened up one of the stems and it was almost like there’s were being eaten from the inside, the roots of the stems are hollow.
4. Fungus still reappears sometimes on the soil.

I don’t want to give up since they’re fighting so hard. I can’t take them outside cause I live in an apartment complex. It currently still freezing cold/winter if that helps. I’d really appreciate any help whatsoever, I’m desperate.

Thank you in advanced

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 4):

This is a combination of factors that involve:

- root rot from over watering and not enough light
- toxicity from the "anti fungus stuff and things that promote growth" you applied
- soil level is too high causing stems to be damp promoting fungus

You might be able to save this plant by:

- lower the soil level so you can see where the roots join the stem
- more light
- less water
- do not fertilize, the plant does not need it at this time, wait till next year
- cut all dead growth away. Sterilize the cutting tool after use with alcohol
- try a warmer location, palms are quite happy from 68 deg F to 80 deg F.
- be patient, it could be some time before the plant grows enough roots to initiate new growth.